# How can I set up IntelliJ, the community version, for working on an EmberJS project?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, intellij-idea, handlebars.js, ecmascript-6

How can I set up IntelliJ, the community version, for working on an EmberJS project so I get nice JavaScript ES6 support, handlebars, etc. Is it actually possible?

I did try WebStorm and it was a bit better, but it wasn't fantastic and I'm not sure whether I'll continue to work with EmberJS so I don't want to purchase it yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

Just install the Ember.js plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8049

**Previously:**

There is a short list on Ember-cli.com website about settings for Webstorm, it is the same for IntelliJ Community Edition.

http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#webstorm

Copy-pasted:

#### WebStorm

If you are using WebStorm with ember-cli, you will need to modify your `.gitignore` file, enable ECMAScript6 settings, and mark certain directories.

First, add the following line to `.gitignore`:

`.idea`

Next, from the WebStorm menu:

`File > Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> ECMAScript6`

Click ‘OK’ to close the Settings modal window.

Next, in Webstorm’s Project window right-click on each of the following directories, go to ‘Mark Directory As’ and mark as indicated:

Mark as Excluded:

```
/tmp
/dist
```

Mark as Resource Root:

```
/
/bower_components
/bower_components/ember-qunit/lib
/public
```

Mark as Test Sources Root:

```
/tests
```

Comment: why do you mark `bower_components` as a resource root?

Comment: Probably doesn't need that... however that was the suggestion on ember-cli website. :) What do you think?